# How to display blog in a section of a page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display blog posts underneath the 'about us' paragraph on an about page by using the code below in a template part. However, it's only returning the title of the actual page and the date info as the date I've edited the page.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <article class="post">
        <header>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="post-details">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time( 'F jS, Y' ); ?>
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> <a href=""><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></a>
                <i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href=""><?php comments_popup_link( 'No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »' ); ?></a>

            </div><!-- post details -->
        </header>

        <div class="post-excerpt">
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?> <a href="post.html">continue reading</a></p>
        </div><!-- post-excerpt -->

        <hr>

    </article><!-- end article -->
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What code do I need to pull my actual blog posts into this section?

Comment: You have to use custom WP_Query here to pull posts as second loop... https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query  see third example, multiple loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet the custom query for your posts is missing. Try something like this:

```
    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    <?php if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
           <article class="post">
                <header>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="post-details">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time( 'F jS, Y' ); ?>
                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> <a href=""><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></a>
                        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href=""><?php comments_popup_link( 'No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »' ); ?></a>

                    </div><!-- post details -->
                </header>

                <div class="post-excerpt">
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?> <a href="post.html">continue reading</a></p>
                </div><!-- post-excerpt -->

                <hr>

            </article><!-- end article -->
        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php 
  // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

        endif; 


    ?>
```

Here you can find an useful tool to generate a Wordpress Query:
https://generatewp.com/wp_query/

Here you can find permitted arguments for Wordpress Query:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

To use your custom query remember to call `have_posts()` and `the_posts()` methods with your query object ( `$custom_query->have_posts()` and `$custom_query->the_post()` in snippet), furthermore is important `wp_reset_postdata()` to restore main query.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I understand how to do it now.